# In do while, document.write does not work (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, do-while, document.write

```
<body>
  <form>    
    <input id="inicio" type="button" value="INICIO"/>   
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById("inicio").addEventListener("click", comenzar, false);

    function comenzar (){
      var aleatorio = Math.round(Math.random()*100);

      // document.write(aleatorio);

      var numDado, intentos;
      numDado=0;
      intentos=0;

      do{
        numDado= prompt("Dime un numero");

        if (aleatorio>numDado){
          //alert("Mas alto");
          document.write("mas alto");
        }

        if(aleatorio<numDado){
          //alert("mas bajo");
          document.write("mas bajo");
        }
      } while(aleatorio!=numDado);

      alert("lo has logrado");
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try to format the code...

Comment: There also isn't a question there

Comment: Don't just dump code, provide an explanation of what your code is supposed to do, what is not working in it. Also format the code so it can be easily read, the Editor provides a preview while editing

Comment: `prompt()` returns a string value, even if its contents are numeric. Comparing a string against a number may not behave as you expect.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. I have worked with all the recommendations here but my problem come again. When I change document.write to alert. The script works as I expect at this phase but if I can use document.write,the program enter in the loop but it does not show the advice. The same problem if I want to print this advice in a textfield. If any  of you have some idea what happens. I will really appreciate it. Thanks indeed.

Comment: @maytelabarga if the answer solved your issue it would be nice if you accepted it! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I think that's an infinite loop.

Try with this

`numDado = numDado * 1`

This will cast *numDado* to number

There's also another issue.

If user presses 'OK' but type nothing, or if he presses 'Cancel'
The game won't stop

You sould add this

```
numDado = prompt("Dime un numero");
if (numDado != null) {
    numDado = numDado * 1
```

Or this

```
numDado = prompt("Dime un numero");
if(numDado == null) return;
numDado = numDado * 1
```

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton

Answer (score 0):

```
numDado= prompt("Dime un numero"); // wrong way
numDado= Number(prompt("Dime un numero")); // right way
```

Because, prompt always get input values as string. If your input value as Numerical string, you don't able use this directly. So you convert Numerical string to Number then use it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possible issues there. I've got no time to test it but try the following:

1º I think you may have an inffinite loop, so try to change your while loop like this:

```
while(numDado = prompt("Dime un número", "")) {
   ...
}
```

2º You have to cast the result to a number (int) because prompt() returns a string. This may help:

```
var numInt = parseInt(numDado)
```

Comment: Number may not be an _int_ though

Comment: You are right but Mayte here is trying to compare an int as she is rounding the random number 'var aleatorio = Math.round(Math.random()*100);' So I guess she is asking for an int. But again, you are right ;)

Comment: Indeed. I guess the best solution would be casting to an int and then comparing that result with some basic error handling. Or as you suggested just converting to Number ;)